# Questions regarding running Apache on Windows

Tags: discussion

We get several questions a day from people trying to run Apache on Windows platforms. Excluding WAMP questions (which are already off-topic), should we allow questions about running Apache on Windows?

Apache is clearly designed to run on *nix operating systems. While it's possible to run it on Windows, every bone in my body says that it's a really bad idea to do so due to reliability issues, performance issues, and supportability issues. If people want to use Apache, great. Do it on Linux or BSD. If they are stuck using Windows, then bite the bullet and use IIS.

So, what are your thoughts on this? Should these questions be closed due to them not demonstrating "reasonable business information technology management practices"?

---

OK, thanks everyone for your input. We'll leave 'em open (as long as they're not close-worthy for some other reason).

Comment: Related: [Apache on Windows in production environment? Why not?](http://serverfault.com/q/211610/126632)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've seen that. Doesn't lend a whole lot to the conversation, though IMHO. "Well it runs..." isn't a great benchmark for whether something is a good idea. It would also run on an RPi, which as we know is a horrible idea for many reasons other than whether or not the application is functional.

Comment: So I shouldn't put a domain controller on my shiny new Raspberry Pi Zero?

Comment: Maybe that's OK if it's merely an RODC.

Comment: Some degree of justification would be nice. I've actually worked in an environment where using an unholy WAMP + python + windows abomination had a technical/business reason.  If its a dev box though, Bad dev, no cookie. In face negative cookies!

Comment: One wild wonder if you know nothing about apache on windows why having someone answer the question is a problem for you.

Comment: @JimB Who said anything about me knowing nothing about Apache on Windows? Topicality of questions does not hinge on whether myself or anyone else on the site is familiar with the topic. Anyway, the discussion is closed - I'm not sure why you thought this comment would be constructive in any way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm going to say "leave them open" just because I've supported a couple of vendor products that require Apache on Windows.  Those were mainstream packages (things like McAfee ePolicy Orchestrator) that mainstream businesses would use.  A fix for a problem with Apache on Windows in a situation like that is not necessarily vendor-specific, and the person asking the question can't just go use IIS instead.

Answer (score 11):

I can't really get behind this there are plenty of Apache httpd systems running on Windows. People should be able to ask questions about them, after all for the majority of issues the answer will be the same and ot OS dependent.

People should though, realise that if their question [relates to an aspect of running Apache httpd on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/741651/apache-error-log-showing-error-line-with-no-date) which is OS specific then the chances of it getting answered is significantly lower as there is less mindshare.